# There is no phonegap.js

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

I'am watching phonegap tutorial. In every tutorial they add phonegap.js. What is the phonegap.js. I cant download it from phonegap site. Is phonegap.js equal to cordova.js?

Comment: PhoneGap was renamed to Cordova.

Comment: You should be able to find cordova.js in the PhoneGap folder you downloaded. For iOS it should be under phonegap-yourVersion/lib/ios/CordovaLib

Comment: There is no download link. Only install link.

Comment: @fuat With the latest version of PhoneGap they changed to using Node.js for building new projects. If you go to that [install page](http://phonegap.com/install/) though and scroll down you should still see archived versions of PhoneGap. If you built a project using PhoneGap 3.0 then cordova.js should already be included in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phonegap.js` was renamed to `cordova.js` at the version 1.5. Check the release notes from the web site [here](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/06/phonegap-1-5-released/).